# Discord bot responds multiple times when clustered with pm2

Tags: javascript, discord.js, pm2

I recently made a discord bot using discord.js. It has been running continuously on my raspberry pi using pm2.
Recently, I switched from pm2's fork mode into cluster mode which utilises all cores.
However, when I now send a command, the bot replies 4 times and I don't know how to make it act like one thread.
Does someone know how to set it up so clustered apps respond once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clustering with PM2 can only be done with stateless applications.  The Discord client represents a statefull session connected to the discord servers (this is not dissimilar to a websocket).  Don't use cluster mode.

Comment: Thank you. I'll use fork mode, then.

Comment: @MaksK is there anything specific you need to do to start the discord bot with pm2? I use Babel with pm2 and I can't start it in fork_mode